# Can't get rid of the ugly border around ImageButton

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm working on an Android App which has a few (Next, Back, ... etc) `Buttons` which are all round and transparent and I use `ImageButton` for those `Buttons`, however the problem is there is always a white border around the `Button` (I use black `background` so it is very ugly) and the button never appears to be round is appears as some sort of a square-ish shape.

Here is what I tried so far :

1. Setting the background of the `ImageButton` in the `activity_mypage.xml` file to

   ```
   android:background="@android:color/transparent"
   ```

   and to

   ```
   android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
   ```

   and to

   ```
   android:background="?android:selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
   ```

   even to

   ```
   android:background="@null"
   ```

   but nothing seems to work on the .xml side.
2. and I tried the following on the MyPage.java file :

   ```
   myBtn.setBackgroundResource(0);
   ```

   and also

   ```
   myBtn.setBackground(null);
   ```

Nothing seems to work anything I do keeps resulting the same (although it removes a gray border from around the `Button` but none of them makes the `Button` completely transparent)

This is a screenshot of the button before applying any of above :
[image: Before Applying any of the above settings/attributes]

And this is a screenshot of the same `Button` after applying any of those attributes (doesn't really matter if I applied it only to the `xml` or only to the java file or to both because all results are the same):
  [image]

This is my xml code for one of my `Buttons` in xml :

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/my_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="37dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="37dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/my_btn"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    />
```

And here is the code for it in the .java file :

```
       ImageButton myBtn= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.my_btn);
       myBtn.setBackground(null);
       myBtn.setBackgroundResource(0);
```

I'm really lost at this every result I found for this query has suggested one of the above methods but none of these seems to work for me..

Comment: it seems your image is having that white border around it.

Comment: can you post your image(my_btn) also

Comment: @VivekMishra I tried a number of transparent images before but they all had the same issue, [Here](https://imgur.com/a/VZg3C) is a link of this same image that I use.

Comment: Do you try to set android:src instead of app:srcCompat

Comment: Might be related to the problem too: you should not put any resources in the `mipmap` folders, they are for launcher icon only. Move it to corresponding `drawable` folders.

Comment: no drawable is perfect working myside

Comment: I think his problem is related to His activity file

Comment: @RobCo that exactly was the problem I added the icon into the `mipmap` directory instead of `drawables`..

Comment: what is the filename of your image? .png or .jpg? load it up in photoshop or gimp, and see if the white is embedded in the image. my guess is that is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after reading some of the posted answers and playing around with the suggestions in my code I noticed that the `icon` was incorrectly loaded into my `mipmap` directory instead of `drawables` and that is because when I imported the `icons` I selected `New` `->` `Image Asset` instead of `Vector Asset` which caused my 'icon' to lose its transparency ...

Thanks to everyone for their replies and answers.

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

to

```
android:background="@null"
```

Comment: I already tried both as stated in the question, it doesn't work for some reason..

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
android:src="@mipmap/yourimage"
```

instead of

`app:srcCompat="@mipmap/my_btn"`

Comment: @LawaFazil what kind of animation do you want ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ImageView` instead of `ImageButton`, so background issue will not occur

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/my_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="37dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="37dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:src="@mipmap/my_btn"
        />
```

Comment: I wanted the button to have the click "animation" when clicked that is why I used ImageButton

Comment: @LawaFazil tell me that have you extend your activity class with Activity or AppCompactActivity

Answer (score 0):

add this to your button

```
android:background="@drawable/template"
```

and create a file name it template in your drawable folder
and add this code to it

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn2imagePressed"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn1imageNotPressed"></item> </selector>
```

Comment: I have found what was causing the problem I will post the solution now..